# Drupal 7 - URL for Notifications of a User

Tags: url, drupal-7, notifications

I am using notifications module with Drupal 7. Users can subscribe to taxonomy terms ans get email notifications. I want to create a menu link for a user to be able to see the subscriptions he has made. The link for this is www.example.com/user/6/notifications.

I want to use something that works for every user. Meaning, the 6 in the url is to be replaced by something. I tried www.example.com/user/**[user-id]**/notifications. It gives access denied error.

www.example.com/user/6/notifications is working perfectly. Tokens module is enabled on the site.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have to fetch logged in user uid using this code

$user->uid and store in subscribe url.
or can use on this page

```
global $user
$uid = $user->uid;
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, but I am new to Drupal. Did you mean the link should look like this: www.example.com/user/$user->uid/notifications